# Issue in running the qiskit tutorial for QSVM

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am trying to run this QSVM tutorial using qiskit from my Python environment using Jupyter Notebook

Firstly it gives me an error that I have to install `qiskit-aqua[cvx]` when I try to run this code -

```
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots=1024, seed_simulator=seed,seed_transpiler=seed)
result = qsvm.run(quantum_instance)
```

Then after I install the above package. I keep on getting the error - 'BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.'

I also try using the following code at the beginning of the notebook as per here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues/924. But no luck.

```
import os 
os.environ['MPMATH_NOSAGE'] = 'true'
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Sourav

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! Quick questions : what is your Python version and the Qiskit version you are running? I remember some problems of versions for old versions of Qiskit with the latest version of Python, you can run this two lines to get both on a notebook `import qiskit.tools.jupyter` and then 
`%qiskit_version_table`

Comment: @Lena added below

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis/issues/419) upgrading to python 3.8 worked to fix the issue, did you try?

Comment: @Lena - No. I cannot upgrade to 3.8. It is a bit restricted env.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with qiskit 0.23.6?

Comment: @Lena- Just tried with qiskit 0.23.6. All other versions remaining the same as below. No luck though.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a new conda env & install all reqd packages in there

Conda create a new env -https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

```
Conda activate your env & install these stuff 

conda install python=3.8.3
conda install -c anaconda pandas
conda install -c anaconda cmake
conda install -c anaconda libxml2
conda install scikit-learn
conda install cryptography
conda install -c anaconda libxslt
conda install -c anaconda pandas
conda install h5py 
conda install pytest
conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy
conda install -c conda-forge pymetis
conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt
conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy
conda install ipywidgets
conda install lxml
conda install wheel

pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider
pip install qiskit-terra
pip install qiskit-ignis 
pip install qiskit-aqua==0.8.2
pip install qiskit-aer==0.7.3
Pip install qiskit  # this will update qiskit aqua
```

After installation try to run this example https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/machine_learning/01_qsvm_classification.ipynb

Comment: Creating a new conda env is not an acceptable solution. creating a completely new conda env is not a solution in my case the end user cannot create a new conda env. The entire purpose wud be defeated. if that is the only solution I need a solution where user can run the tutorial just doing only pip install from teh Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I finally could make it work with

qiskit-aqua[cvx]
qiskit-terra': '0.16.4',
qiskit-aer': '0.7.6',
qiskit-ignis': '0.5.2',
qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.12.2',
qiskit-aqua': '0.8.2',
qiskit': '0.24.1'

And by increasing the core and memory.

Thanks for all help.

Regards,
Sourav